# How to Move IBM Rational ClearCase Solaris VOB Server VOBs to a new domain

Tags: solaris, clearcase, nas

Our `Clearcase Environment` details as follows,

```
Server Operating System: SunOS 5.10 Generic.
Clearcase Server Version: ClearCase 7.0.0.2-IFIX02.
Storage Type: NAS (Network-attached storage).
Client Side clearcase used on: Windows, Linux and Ubuntu operating systems.
```

**Requirement Description:-**

We have Sun Solaris clearcase VOB server, we need to move our VOB server to new domain, Therefore could you share the best ways to migrate our VOBs to new domain.

Comment: "new domain"? But still the same kind of solaris server?

Comment: Yes. Same Server VOBs we want to access in new domain.

Comment: PL, so as in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_mvvob_ux.htm then?

Comment: I meant: "OK", not "PL" ;)

Comment: Since the server isn't actually moving, not quite.. Where are the views? If on windows, you'll need to check everything in and REMOVE the views. If on Unix, you may not need to.

Comment: Team, It was only Windows user PCs moved to new domain.So i just requested System Admin to create new ALBD Service account and Clearcase Admin and Vob groups in new domain. After that in user PCs i just changed albd account and unregistred old view and again registered with new host name then executed fix_prot. Now everything working fine. Thank you team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It was only Windows user PCs moved to new domain.

Then it is described by [Domain user and group accounts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_domainadm_accounts.htm)
That does require a new service Albd Account, in order to `net start` the albd service.
But also:

- [setting the domain accounts for the Rational ClearCase administrators group and Rational ClearCase server process user](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_domainadm_accounts_manual.htm)
- [setting the Rational ClearCase primary group](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_domainadm_accounts_ccprimary.htm)